# How to SUM Grouped and Counted Field

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, count, sum

I need to `Sum` of `Counted` and `Grouped columns`. By the way I need to `Where Clause` for specific condition.

Here is my complicated query;

```
SELECT COUNT(id) AS Counted, State FROM Table1
GROUP BY State
HAVING State NOT IN (2,3)

UNION ALL

SELECT SUM(Say) AS SubSUM, State FROM (
    SELECT COUNT(b.id) AS SubCount, b.State FROM Table1 AS b
    GROUP BY b.State
    HAVING b.State IN (2,3)
) S GROUP BY S.State
```

I just want to know how many rows I have which is `State` 2 and 3. I hope explained.

Comment: Please edit your question with sample data and desired results.

Comment: What is your database?

Comment: @MaciejLos I'm using SQL Server

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you can do what you want with conditional aggregation.  Something like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(id) AS total,
       SUM(CASE WHEN State NOT IN (2, 3) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
       SUM(CASE WHEN State IN (2, 3) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM Table1;
```